# How to retrieve json in original nested form in apache solr?

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I am using **apache solr** for **text search**. I have `nested document structure`. This is `one.json` file :

```
{
"id": "1",
"info": {
       "first_name": "John",
       "last_name": "Doe",
       "gender": "male"
        }
}
```

I created a solr core and posted `one.json` in it.Solr `indexed and flattened the above document's nested structure` , I guess for better indexing in following form:

```
{
    "id":["1"],
    "info.first_name":["John"],
    "info.last_name":["Doe"],
    "info.gender":["male"]
}
```

Now, when I make the search query,the `result is in flattened form`.

For my requirement, `I want the response json in original nested form`.

How can this be achieved in Solr ? Is there `some tool that I can use with Solr to get the original nested json` while making search?

**Addition:**

I am using `solr 6.3.0`. When I added the json file to the core, solr `automatically indexed the json file`. A `managed-schema.xml` was generated by solr.

Here is a `portion of managed-schema.xml` where fields are defined:

```
<field name="_root_" type="string" docValues="false" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="_text_" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
  <field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="info.first_name" type="strings"/>
  <field name="info.gender" type="strings"/>
  <field name="info.last_name" type="strings"/>
```

Comment: Could please show us schema.xml of defined fields?

Comment: @Oyeme I have added the contents of `managed-schema.xml` in the description. I have added those parts where fields are defined. These all contents of managed-schema.xml were generated by solr itself when I added the json into core.

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible with **srcField** parameter as described in [the Reference Guide section on processing custom JSON](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Transforming+and+Indexing+Custom+JSON). Notice the limitation that your nested document will be indexed as a single document.

The techproduct example has the srcField configured, if you want to test it with a shipped schema.