# How to Retrieve and Query JSON type fields in Apache Solr 6.5

Tags: json, apache, solr, lucene, full-text-search

My Goal is to retrieve JSON type fields in an Solr index and also perform search queries on such fields.

I have the following documents in Solr Index and using the auto generated schema utilizing schemaless feature in Solr.

POST http://localhost:8983/solr/test1/update?commitWithin=1000

```
[
    {"id" : "1", "type_s":"book", "title_t" : "The Way of Kings", "author_s" : "Brandon Sanderson",
"miscinfo": {"provider": "orielly", "site": "US"}
 },
 {"id" : "2", "type_s":"book", "title_t" : "The Game of Thrones", "author_s" : "James Sanderson",
"miscinfo": {"provider": "pacman", "site": "US"}
 }
 ]
```

I see the JSON types are stored as strings in the schemaField type as seen in the output for following

GET http://localhost:8983/solr/test1/schema/fields

```
{
      "name":"miscinfo",
      "type":"strings"}
```

I had tried using srcField as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41566634/how-to-retrieve-json-in-original-nested-form-in-apache-solr). However, a query to retrieve json type returns empty response. Below are the GET request used for the same

GET http://localhost:8983/solr/test1/select?q=1&fl=miscinfo&wt=json

GET http://localhost:8983/solr/test1/select?q=1&fl=miscinfo,source_s:[json]&wt=json

Also, the search queries for values inside JSON type fields return empty response

http://localhost:8983/solr/test1/select?q=pacman&wt=json

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "q": "pacman",
      "json": "",
      "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  }
}
```

Please help in searching object types in Solr.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Response+Writers

> **JSON Response Writer** A very commonly used Response Writer is the
>   JsonResponseWriter, which formats output in JavaScript Object Notation
>   (JSON), a lightweight data interchange format specified in specified
>   in RFC 4627. Setting the wt parameter to json invokes this Response
>   Writer. Here is a sample response for a simple query like
>   q=id:VS1GB400C3&wt=json:

Comment: I have checked this link and already using wt=json to get JSON response. However, I am facing issue in retrieving fields from indexed data that are of type JSON.

Comment: The only difference I see is the indent=true but I don't think this should be the reason... searching here I found this: 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Transforming+and+Indexing+Custom+JSON

it is setting this: "-H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '"

Comment: Yes, I don't see any difference in the output after adding indent=true in the HTTP request

Comment: This is just relevant for how the output is sent back to the client and not for how data is queried.

Comment: Agreed MatsLindh. I am still haven't found the solution for the problem.